# how to use a method inside a com dll into C#?

Tags: com, dll

how to use  a method inside a com dll into C#  ?

Answer (score 3):

[Best way to access COM objects from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c)

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to the com dll and .net will automatically give a wrapper class and by using that you can call functions inside the dll.