# Quote From MSDN On RegAsm

Tags: .net, com, regasm

I want to know what they really mean by this statement. Does it mean regasm.exe doesn't actually register types? Or, does it mean that you need to register every instance you make (which seems odd)? Etc..

[image: Taken from: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool]

Comment: regasm registers what COM needs to create instance: progids, interfaces, classids, typelibs, coclasses, etc. you don't have to register instances

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10188202/4645236

Comment: In short, "They" refers to the "classes", not the "instances". They even say one sentence earlier: "Once a class is registered..."