# Hiding the Drive script in QTP/UFT

Tags: hp-uft

Is it possible to hide the Driver script for each execution in HP-UFT?

Comment: What do you mean by `hide Driver script`..?

Comment: we have designed an UI to fetch Test cases on Execution request invoke UI will fetch list of test cases which with execution falg Yes so then UFT will be  open this execution will done with help of Driver script. after Execution user can see the driver script in as test case in Recent test cases list, so we want to hide that would it be possible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a driver script, you can create the COM object of Quicktest.Application inside your UI application itself. If you are using Excel as UI, you can use the same driver script code in a function and it will work in excel. All languages will have similar methods to create COM objects. A C# example would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp)