# C# Return value calling 3rd party com object

Tags: c#, com

COM objects are brand new territory for me and I've searched quite a bit with no luck.  I'm calling a 3rd parties COM object and I can get it to do what it is supposed to, but it always returns null and I need the value for the next step.  The sample for it is in Python and it returns as expected.  My code is below, how do I set this up so I can get the return value?

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("3rdParty.Name");

object publisher = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

object[] args = new object[6];

//fill in the args

//It works and does what it is supposed to behind the scenes, 
//but need the int return value.  
//Right now it is always null
int? handle = (int?)t.InvokeMember("DoYourThing", 
                                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
                                    null, 
                                    publisher, 
                                    args);
```

Comment: Why don't you just [use a COM interop wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp)? It'll turn this whole thing into a trivial task.

Comment: I didn't know that existed, as I said this is all new to me.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Per [Lynn Crumbling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656243/lynn-crumbling)'s comment, this was the solution.

[Best way to access COM objects from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp)