# C# - Get list of all the sensors in a Windows Device

Tags: c#, .net, window

I'm working on a simple C# Back-end App where I've to collect all the data coming from different kind of sensors that are connected to windows Device, like " Gyroscope " , " Gravity " sensors. etc.
After a lot of internet search I couldn't find anything useful. The only option that is a little bit closer to my query is UWP Apps, But I'm not working on UWP app now.
I'm working with Simple Console C# Application , Can any body help me to find out some good and useful API for windows sensors management ?

Comment: Check out WMI APIs they shall provide you all system details

Comment: This is good. But it is only applicable for C++ .

Comment: You mean integrated sensors usually found on mobile devices or peripherals sensors connected to a pc (desktop application)?

Comment: Yes.. Sensors are integrated in a mobile device. And I'm running windows 10 in that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Windows sensor API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318913(v=vs.85).aspx) for accessing information from the sensors. 
The Sensor API is working via set of COM interfaces. Using COM interfaces from c# is also possible and there are a lot info about it: [Best way to access COM objects from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635839/best-way-to-access-com-objects-from-c-sharp) or directly at Windows.com with c# samples for sensors API: [Calling Windows 10 APIs From a Desktop Application](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).