# vb6 dll different behavior when debugging

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb6, com-interop, crystal-reports-2008

This is very common case where i have about 2500 dll's.
All of those dll's are made with vb6.

Scenario: Run the main .exe file and call the .dll from it. When running Crystal report view it works as a charm.

Scenario 2: Run the .exe file which is made with .NET through debug mode works as a charm.

Scenario 3: **Run the .exe file which is made with .NET through RUNTIME Throw the exception shown bellow**.

> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 0F5E6BD0

Full stack message available on link: [Full exception message](https://pastebin.com/ujWSj0La)

Tried with two ways.

1. Adding the .dll to .exe as a references
2. Adding it through `CreateObject`

This is one my my work.

```
Dim obj As Object
obj = CreateObject("Partneri.clPartneri")

Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallByName(obj, "PrikaziFormu", CallType.Method, cConrADO,
                                         cConADO, False, "", cJezik, rTagovi, rPrevodi, rPrava, 0, 0, cUsername)
```

Please keep in mind: When running this through debug everything works great.

The only workaround which i am using now is going like Create .exe made in vb6. Call that .exe from .net exe and pass a option name as a parameter. On form load it will set up the object which works great.

Additional: When running crystal report print on load throws
[image]

Comment: VB6 is 32-bit only. Is your .NET application is running as 64bit when the error occurs?

Comment: i think you shoul d try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540578/how-to-use-method-from-vb6-dll-in-net?answertab=active#tab-top , but for 5000 dlls i hope you get a better answer

Comment: @DaveInCaz you wouldn't believe how much i expected that would solve the issue. Setting the Target CPU - x86 didn't solve it

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the exe as administrator to rule out if it’s a permissions thing?
In debug mode you’re probably running as admin, but the exe won’t be.

I had similar errors when calling .NET COM interop dlls from VB6, but that was caused by using inheritance in the .NET classes.
Or so it seemed.

Comment: Tried that on start. Even so it has local admin privs. And running it as administrator as well didnt worked

Comment: Try adding some code to see if the object was created before the call. The error suggests the object isn’t being created.